# GAS Spreadsheet script to create and open / download Drive PDF in Custom Dialog

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, drive

Good morning, I have some scripts with which I save a PDF file in a specific folder and then send it by email. Everything works fine, even if my code is not optimized. [Recently I put a previous query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312433/script-gas-spreadsheet-crear-y-descargar-pdf-guardado-en-drive) where they helped me how to create a Custom Dialog to show the link to download the PDF file, however when I click on the link I automatically get error 400 which makes it impossible for me to download that PDF. I still cannot determine what I am failing, besides that, I would like the PDF to be displayed in the Custom Dialog. The code:

```
function CrearPDF(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nombreHoja = 'LP con Seguros';
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(nombreHoja).activate();
var gid = sheet.getSheetId()

var fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");//Captura de la fecha de acuerdo a la zona horaria
var dni = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!B1').getValues();
var nrocuenta = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!C6').getValues();
var correo = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!K13').getValues();
var valRegisSimul=spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!P10').getValues();
var nombrePDF = valRegisSimul + " de LP DNI "+dni+" " +fecha+".pdf";

var ssID = spreadsheet.getId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                        "?format=pdf&"+
                                                        "size=a4&"+
                                                        "portrait=true&"+
                                                        "scale=4&"+
                                                        //"top_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"bottom_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"left_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"right_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        "gridlines=false&"+
                                                        "printnotes=false&"+
                                                        //"pageorder=2&"+
                                                        "horizontal_alignment=CENTER&"+
                                                        "vertical_alignment=TOP&"+
                                                        "printtitle=false&"+
                                                        "sheetnames=false&"+
                                                        "fzr=false&"+
                                                        "fzc=false&"+
                                                        "attachment=false&"+
                                                        "gid=" + gid + "&"+
                                                        "r1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "c1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "r2=" + 62 + "&"+
                                                        "c2=" + 8;

var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

// Creamos un fichero con el Blob anterior y le cambiamos el nombre 
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(nombrePDF).getAs('application/pdf');

var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders(); // En esta variable se almacenan solo los carpetas del directorio raiz
var nombrecarpeta = "DNIs de LP y Simulaciones";


  if(folders.hasNext() == false)//Para cuando no hay carpetas o folder aún en el Drive
  {
    var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
    NewFolder.createFile(pdf);


      var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());


  }
  else //En el caso de que sí haya carpetas o folder en el Drive, los recorre hasta encontrar el nombre "nombrecarpeta" sino lo encuentra la creará y ahí guarda el archivo
  {
    while (folders.hasNext())
    {
      var folder = folders.next();
      if(folder.getName() == nombrecarpeta)// en el caso de que exista una carpeta con el nombre terminamos la iteracion de las carpetas
    {
      var folderid = folder.getId();
      var Transfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
      Transfolder.createFile(pdf);

      var file = Transfolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());

      break;
    }
    else 
    {// Creamos la carpeta en el caso de que aún no exista y guardamos el archivo en la nueva carpeta
      var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
      NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());
      break;
    }
   }   
  }

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LP con Seguros'), true);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Obtiene el nombre del archivo PDF recién creado, así como su contenido
   var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(); // sin la opción getBytes obtendríamos un archivo sin contenido
   var attach = {fileName:nombrePDF,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

   var subject = valRegisSimul + ' de Crédito Efectivo DNI ' + dni + ' ' + fecha;

   var html = '<body>' + '<strong>' + ' <p>Estimado(a)' + '</strong>' + '</p>' + 
      '<p>A continuación encontrará adjunto el archivo del plan de pagos de su Crédito Efectivo, recuerde siempre realizar los abonos al número de cuenta del préstamo.</p>' + 
      '<p style="text-align: left;">==> El número de cuenta del Crédito Efectivo a donde se deben hacer los abonos es: ' + '<strong>' + nrocuenta + '</strong>' + '</p>'

  //Muestra un Popup preguntando si deseas enviar la transferencia por correo  
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.alert('Se completó el registro correctamente, ¿Desea enviar el plan de pagos al correo registrado: '+ correo + ' ?' + '\n\n' + 'Caso contrario, el archivo ' + nombrePDF + ' sólo se guardará en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Si la respuesta es si, mandará el correo, de lo contrario termina el programa
  if (response == ui.Button.YES)
  {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(correo, subject, "Cuerpo", {htmlBody:html, attachments:[attach]});
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se envió correctamente el plan de pagos al correo '+ correo + '.' + '\n\n' + 'Mencione regreso por seguros y número de cuenta del Crédito efectivo');

     }else
     {
       //Solo por referencia
       Logger.log('El archivo '+ nombrePDF + ' quedó guardado en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive');
     };

  var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
  var html = '<a href=" + url + " target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Descargar PDF de Google Drive";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);

  }
```

[Custom Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttam8.png) [Error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPLoi.png)
Thanks in advance for the answers I will receive.
Thanks to @Adam Stevenson for the support, I corrected the code, however I still can't download the PDF, now I get a different error. Attachment screenshot.
[Error after correcting the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5tsl.png)

Comment: Hello! I recommend reviewing the [Debugging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging) section of the Apps Script troubleshooting guide. It provides some helpful instructions for how to log and inspect the values of parameters as they get passed from different areas of your code. When you get the 404 error, what does the URL look like? You may want to do some debugging to inspect the value of `var url` after it is defined.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the recommendation,the URL: https://n-2wfyhr7t4ohqx36zd25fgtzsl4shrgg6qqmmoci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/+%20url%20+ and when I click on the link it takes me to the following address: https: // accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fn-2wfyhr7t4ohqx36zd25fgtzsl4shrgg6qqmmoci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2F%2B%2520ur2%2%%5%25 2wfyhr7t4ohqx36zd25fgtzsl4shrgg6qqmmoci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com% 2F% 2B% 2520url% 2520% 2B which generates this error message:"400.That's an error.The requested URL was not found on this server"

Comment: Thanks! I think I see the issue. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `html`:

```
var html = '<a href=" + url + " target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
```

…you did not break up the string with single quotes `'`. The double quote `"` does not end the string since you started it with single quotes. So `+ url +` is just being read as part of the string. The corrected code:

```
var html = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I attached the new error.